# Python Selenium Chrome - send_keys() not sending keys during 2nd iteration of loop when scraping WhitePages

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, sendkeys

I'm writing a function that opens WhitePages, searches a person's name and location, and scrapes their phone number and address. It does this by:

1. Navigating to [whitepages.com](https://www.whitepages.com/)
2. Finding the name `<input>` and sending it keys (`send_keys(persons_name)`)
3. Finding the location `<input>` and sending it keys (`send_keys(my_city)`)
4. Finding the search button `<button>` and clicking it
5. On the search results page, finding the link `<a>` to the person's page
6. On the person's page, finding and returning the person's landline and address

When I run the function in a loop on a list of names, the function runs successfully on the first iteration, but not the second. For testing purposes, I'm running the WebDriver with a head/GUI so that I can verify what is going on, and it seems as though on the second iteration, the function successfully finds the name `<input>` **but doesn't input the person's name via send_keys()**, then successfully finds the location `<input>` and successfully inputs the location, then successfully finds and `click()`s the search button.

Since there must be a name in the name `<input>` for a search to be done, no search occurs and red text under the name `<input>` appears saying "Last name is required" (that's how I know for sure `send_keys()` is failing), and then I get a `NoSuchElementException` when the program tries to find a search result element that doesn't exist since no search results page was loaded.

(Note: by default, WhitePages denies access to the program when trying to hit search; the `options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')` in the code below circumvents that.)

**So, what may be happening that is causing `send_keys()` to fail, and how do I fix it?**

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# for passing a URL as a service object into the Chrome webdriver initializing method
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# for clicking buttons
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
# raised when using find_element() and no element exists matching the given criteria
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
# for specifying to run the browser headless (w/o UI) and to surpress warnings in console output
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
# for choosing an option from a dropdown menu
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

def scrape_individual_info_wp(driver, individual_name, city_state):

    # FIND INDIVIDUAL ON WHITEPAGES & NAVIGATE TO THEIR INDIVIDUAL PAGE

    driver.get('https://www.whitepages.com/')

    # find name input
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form/div/div/div/div/input").send_keys(individual_name) # attempt to find the input *relatively*
    
    # find location input
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form/div/div/following-sibling::div/div/div/input").send_keys(city_state)

    # find & click search button
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form/div/div/button").click()

    # FIND INDIVIDUAL IN SEARCH RESULTS

    # click (first) free search result link
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='results-container']/a").click()


    # SCRAPE PERSON'S INFO
    
    landline = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Landlines')]/following-sibling::div/a").text.strip()
    address_info = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(),'Current Address')]/parent::div/div/div/div/a").text.strip().split('\n')

    address = address_info[0]
    city_state_zip = address_info[1]

    return [driver.current_url, address, city_state_zip, landline]



# selenium webdriver setup
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# for the webdriver; suppresses warnings in terminal
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

# options.add_argument("--headless")
# options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
# options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

# below, you provide the path to the WebDriver for the browser of your choice, not the path to the browser .exe itself
# the WebDriver is a browser extension that you must install in order for Selenium to work with that browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(r'C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive\Documents\Gray Property Group\Prospecting\Python\Selenium WebDriver for Chrome\chromedriver.exe'), options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# driver.maximize_window()

from time import sleep

names = ['Kevin J Haggerty', 'Patricia B Halliday', 'David R Harb', 'Jeffrey E Hathway', 'Hanshin Hsieh']

for name in names:

    print(name + ':')

    individual_info = scrape_individual_info_wp(driver, name, 'Manchester, NH')

    for field in individual_info:

        print('\t' + field)

    print('\n')

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Kevin J Haggerty:
        https://www.whitepages.com/name/Kevin-J-Haggerty/Bedford-NH/PLyZ4BaGl8Q
        26 Southgate Dr  
        Bedford, NH 03110
        (603) 262-9114   


Patricia B Halliday:     
Traceback (most recent call last):

(...)

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='results-container']/a"}
```

Screenshot of browser (see arrow / red text):
[image]

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try with below code once.

Navigate to the Website once and can use `driver.back()` to come back to the original Page.

User **Explicit wait** to wait for the elements to appear. And can use good locators like `ID` or `CLASS_NAME` to locate the elements.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


def scrape_individual_info_wp(driver, individual_name, city_state):
    name_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "desktopSearchBar")))
    name_field.clear() # Clear the field to enter a new name
    name_field.send_keys(individual_name)
    state_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "pa-3")))
    state_field.clear() # Clear the field and enter the state
    state_field.send_keys(city_state)
    search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "wp-search")))
    search.click()
    time.sleep(2) # Using Sleep to make sure the data is loaded. Can use Waits to wait for the data to appear and extract the same.
    # Code to scarpe data.
    driver.back()


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service= Service("C:/expediaproject/Chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"))
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

driver.get("https://www.whitepages.com/")

names = ['Kevin J Haggerty', 'Patricia B Halliday', 'David R Harb', 'Jeffrey E Hathway', 'Hanshin Hsieh']
state = "Manchester, NH"

for name in names:
    scrape_individual_info_wp(driver, name, state)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the scripts is reopening the page if any input is not empty when the script runs.
(There are too many scripts on the page; I was not able to narrow down which one it is.)

A simple solution is to add `sleep(1)` after `driver.get(...)`.

```py
driver.get('https://www.whitepages.com/')
sleep(1)  # Add this
```

## Power usage

`sleep(1)` significantly slows down the script, especially if looping through many `names`.

Instead, we can use two tabs alternately and prepare each tab for the next-next iteration.

Setup before loop:

```py
driver.get('https://www.whitepages.com/')
driver.execute_script('window.open("https://www.whitepages.com/")')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
next_index = 1
```

Prepare for the next and next-next iterations after processing each `name`:

```py
for name in names:

    ...

    # Prepare this tab for next-next iteration
    driver.get('https://www.whitepages.com/')
    # Switch to another tab for next iteration
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[next_index])
    next_index = 1 - next_index
```

Comment out `driver.get(...)` in `scrape_individual_info_wp` function:

```py
# driver.get('https://www.whitepages.com/')
```

Answer (score -1):

You may create a new driver for each person, so in each iteration you will start off from the home page and navigate to your desired pages.

I did these kinds of things using Selenium in Python, and this was my common approach when scraping multiple pages.

```
names = ['Kevin J Haggerty', 'Patricia B Halliday', 'David R Harb', 'Jeffrey E Hathway', 'Hanshin Hsieh']

for name in names:

    print(name + ':')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:/expediaproject/Chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"))

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

    driver.get("https://www.whitepages.com/")

    individual_info = scrape_individual_info_wp(driver, name, 'Manchester, NH')

    for field in individual_info:

        print('\t' + field)

    print('\n')

    driver.quit()
```

Comment: You can remove the wait.

Comment: @NBG Why is it necessary to create a new driver for each iteration? What is the underlying problem that is solved / circumvented by creating a new driver for each iteration?

Comment: You said : "When I run the function in a loop on a list of names, the function runs successfully on the first iteration, but not the second.". The method that I told you to check will solve this issue because it will bring you back to the main/login page for each iteration.

Comment: What you tried to do is to log in, enter the account page, then try to log in again even though the site won't allow you...

Comment: @pmadhu 's answer will also work perfectly, but if any random pop-up pops up, it has a tendency to turn chaotic (speaking out of experience ;)).